# Debugging Nunit tests in Visual Studio C# Express 2010

Tags: c#, debugging, nunit, visual-studio-express

I've followed this advice to get debugging working for NUnit tests.

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NUnitCSharpExpress.aspx

However, i have several tests that do `Assert.Throws<...>`, which causes the debugger to break when the exception i'm testing for occurs, when really i want it to break if an exception occurs outside of those calls.

How can i get the debugger to ignore exceptions caused from within these kinds of methods?

---

EDIT: I've event tried the below, which doesn't work!

```
[Test]
public void InstanciatingWithNullParameterThrowsException()
{
    try
    {
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => new CachedStreamingEnumerable<int>(null));
        // This still throws and stops be being able to debug tests called after this one
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I would also like an answer to this problem, which none of the answers below is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what worked for me (although in Visual Studio Professional, not Express, but I guess that should not matter).

- Bring up the "Exceptions" Dialog as suggested by Ninjapig.
- Click on the `Add...` Button, to open the "New Exception" dialog.
- Select "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in the drop down box
- In the Edit box enter "NUnit.Framework.AssertionException".
- Click `OK` to close the "New Exception" dialog.
- Back in the "Exceptions" dialog make sure that both checkboxes (`Thrown` *and* `User-unhandled`) are *unchecked*.

Now, the debugger should completely ignore a NUnit assertion failure (i.e. a thrown, caught or not, `NUnit.Framework.AssertionException`).

**UPDATE**: This will only prevent from breaking into the debugger, it cannot ignore the exception itself; i.e. it will not alter the actual program flow. Appart from changing or replacing or encapsulating the Assert-calls in try-catch blocks, I don't think there is anything that can achieve that (at least not automatically).

Comment: That didn't work as the debugger is breaking when the exception i'm testing for is thrown, not if the assert fails. In my case it's a `NullReferenceException` i'm getting.

Comment: @George Duckett: OK, now im confused ;-) I understood, that you want to specifically not break into the debugger for failures of NUnit's Assert.*() operations; which manifest themselves as `NUnit.Framework.AssertionException`s being thrown. Of course, "ignore" in this case means not breaking into the debugger, the program will of course get the exception and proceed according to it. If you want to do as if that exception never happened, I guess there is nothing you can really do, except not throwing it in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, i'll try and clarify. In my tests i'm checking whether a particular exception occurs. When i invoke nunit using the method i found it breaks when that exception i'm looking for occurs. Since i'm actually testing for the occurrence of that exception i want to ignore it to move onto tests that i actually want to debug.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't break on any nunit exception, it breaks before that, when my library being tested correctly causes an `ArgumentNullException`, that is what i want to ignore.

Comment: Can't you simply "uncheck" for the exception types you do *not* want to break it (yet they still occur or course). I thought that was an AssertionException, but now it sounds it is all the others.

Comment: That may be what i have to do, but really i'd like to still break on other occurrences of those exceptions (i just want to ignore the ones in the `Assert.Throws` calls).

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain if VS2010 Express has this option, but you can choose the exceptions to break on .

Go to the 'Debug' menu, then select 'Exceptions'
[image: Menu options]

and from here you can select what exceptions to break on
[image: Exceptions selection window]

Comment: Nice idea, however i don't want to not break on specific exceptions, i want to not break if they are thrown from within an `Assert.Throws` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up referencing `nunit-gui-runner.dll` and invoking it like

```
NUnit.Gui.AppEntry.Main(new string[] { Dll });
```

This brings up the NUnit gui. I can then run the specific test i'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Although your original approach (without the need for a `try...catch` block) works for most exception types, `ArgumentNullException` doesn't work. I fixed it like this:

```
[Test]
public void InstanciatingWithNullParameterThrowsException()
{
    bool isArgumentNullExceptionThrown = false;
    try
    {
       new CachedStreamingEnumerable<int>(null);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException)
    {
        isArgumentNullExceptionThrown = true;
    }
    Assert.That(isArgumentNullExceptionThrown);
}
```

It's not as elegant, but it does seem to work.