# Break on exception, except *here* (Visual Studio 2010 C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception

Debug menu - Exceptions - put a tick in Thrown on the Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

When you do this it breaks on all exceptions which is great.

You can add other exceptions to that pack, and or enable or disable individuals, but that's a bit of effort.

Is there a way to supress the break into debugger using a source directive? Some sort of comment or pragma or anything like that?

I have one bit of code where I can't, not have an exception thrown and it is a bit of a pain having the debugger break on it. I prefer to have VS break on any exception thrown though, just, in this case, no this one.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the DebuggerStepThrough attribute on the method that contains the code that you don't want to break on.  You should isolate the specific lines of code that throw the exception into a smaller method and annotate that method with the DebuggerStepThrough attribute so you're not affecting the rest of your existing method.

Comment: This answer could probably be applied to this question too: [Debugging Nunit tests in Visual Studio C# Express 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6943719)

Comment: Perfect, hadn't thought of that Brian :)  George, I've tried your suggestion, but it is still a pain having to enable and disable and leave that one disabled.

Comment: Tried your answer -- didn't work.  Still get the debugger-break:

System.Exception occurred _HResult=-2147417842 _message=The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. ...

This is in the code:

    _ctorTimerSetup(ref _timer, ref _useThreadPoolTimer);

[DebuggerStepThrough]
void _ctorTimerSetup(ref DispatcherTimer timer, ref bool useThreadPoolTimer)
{
    try
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, _intervalMsecs) };
    }
    catch
    {
        useThreadPoolTimer = true;
    }
}