# How to prevent debugger breaking at exception

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception

I have this small method that helps me establish, if log4net is defined:

```
private static bool IsLog4netDefined()
{
    return ExceptionHelper.Ignore(() => Assembly.Load("log4net,...")) != null;
}
```

While debugging unit tests, which don't use log4net, this method causes debugger to break on the exception being thrown, which drives me crazy. The exception is of course expected and is ignored.

**I don't want to disable this particular exception** in Debug -> Exceptions, as it is pretty generic (*FileNotFoundException*). **I don't want to change any global VS** settings.

Is there a way (something like pre-processor directive) to disable VS breaking in this method?

Comment: How about providing the file that was missing in the first place?

Comment: @CJohnson No file is missing. It's a valid scenario in which there is no log4net.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`DebuggerStepThrough` attribute on the method that contains the code that you don't want to break on

[DebuggerStepThrough attribute solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736339/break-on-exception-except-here-visual-studio-2010-c)

Comment: Tried that on both IsLog4netDefined and Ignore - does not work.

Comment: I would guess that's because the actual method is a lambda, try extracting the lambda and putting the attribute on there